# TestNG shows No tests found. Nothing was run

Tags: testng, testng.xml

I have 3 modules in my automation framework. When I Add my testNG.xml to the "AutoFlowtest" module, it runs perfectly. I need to take out the testNG.xml from all 3 modules and run it. In this case, it shows

Below error

```
...
... TestNG 7.4.0 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...


===============================================
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
All Test Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Here is my project structure.

[image]

Here is my TestNG XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite" verbose="2">
    
    <test name="LoginPage_Tests" preserve-order="true" >
        <packages>
             <package name="./AutoFW-tests/src/test/java/Tests_LoginPage"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How should I give my package name? with . or / it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For run tests in a multimodule project I can suggest you 2 options:

**Option 1**

Create testng-suite xml files per each module and run all of them or partially.

run all tests:

```
mvn clean test
```

run for some modules:

```
mvn clean test -pl moduleA,moduleB
```

---

**Option 2**

Create a new test module (e.g. with `testAllModule` artifactId), which includes all test-jar dependencies from other modules.

See this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/sharing-test-classes-between-multiple-modules-in-a

With the 2nd approach, you'll be able to keep super-testng-suite xml which references multiple modules tests.

```
mvn clean test -pl testAllModule
```

I've not tried particularly the same way to run tests, but I've used the same approach (with creating a new test module) to generate code-coverage report for all submodules.